# Is there a way to get a history of Facebook profiles that I've visited?

Tags: facebook

I have visited a profile on Facebook recently but now I've forgotten the name of person. Is there a way that I can get a history of the profiles which I have already visited?

I am currently using Android Facebook application

Answer (score 2):

[From Facebook help center](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151863512348777),

> To view your activity log on the Android app, first go to your timeline. Under your cover photo, you should see a group of tiles (ex: About, Photos, Friends). Swipe the tiles left until you see the Activity Log tile, then tap on the tile to view your activity log.

[Then](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151863512348777),

> - Tap **Activity Log** > **Filter**
> - Scroll down and tap **Search**

---

For the desktop version, click on the little down arrow at the top left of the screen, then Activity Log, then MORE then scroll down to Select.

Comment: There is no down arrow at the top left is there?

Comment: This is only searches, not profile visits in general. If the OP forgot the name of the person then presumably they didn't get to that person's profile by searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your earlier visited pages if only you have done any comments or likes like that.  Otherwise you cannot .

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this in the Android app. At least if you were in the desktop version you might be able to look through your web browser history...